# Where to find blood orgy?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

In Stan's room  on the floor there is this invitation to the annual blood orgy,followed by some arrows.

[image]

The arrows are obviously directions but from where to start ?

Comment: ...to continue with traditional "stick of truth" titles xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrows are turns you should take after entering **Lost Forest**.
This is the forest on the right,to enter it you can go right from the Kenny's house or U-Store-it.

You will need to have your first magic(fart) unlocked to bypass the rats.Once in the forest  go **Right** to the end of the screen until new "section" starts then go **Up,Right,Down,Right**.

If done right you will find :

> Christmas Critters.You will then be given
>  the option to accept or renounce their lord. Renouncing him will just
>  close the dialogue until you come back. And accepting him will get you
>  grand 12 new friends,with some fun facebook updates.